# Erro de indentação

Tags: python, sintaxe, python-kivy, indentação

Estou tentando criar um `TextInput` no Kivy e definir as suas dimensões, só que sempre que coloca as suas dimensões da erro:

> invalid indentation,must be a multiple of 4 spaces.

Eu ainda não entendi o porque esta dando esse erro.

```
FloatLayout:

TextInput:
    size_hint:1., .5
    pos_hint{'x':.35,'y':.56}


Button:
    size_hint:.3,.1
    pos_hint:{'x':.35,'y':.1}
    text:'1'
Button:
    size_hint:.3,.1
    pos_hint:{'x':.35,'y':.5}
    text:'2'
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 1):

Provavelmente porque está misturando espaços com tabulação, são caracteres diferentes. O erro é bastante claro, você usou 4 espaços para indentação e deve ser assim em todo o código. Inclusive posso quase garantir que o primeiro está com a indentação errada, deve ser um nível acima, mas pode ser que só errou na hora de postar aqui. Por isso sempre digo:

[image: Enquanto você não souber o que cada caractere do seu código faz, até mesmo o espaço em branco, você ainda não sabe programar]

Moral da estória: precisa aprender tudo da linguagem, precisa entender os detalhes mais obscuros, precisa aprender de forma estruturada.

Comment: Verdade, ainda não sei programar e estou praticando para aprender. O problema era que eu não sabia que o TextInput ele usa apenas uma orientação comparado 
a outros widget em linguagem Kivy. Em python eu consigo usar o TextiInput e outros tipos de orientação. Era por isso que dava erro de endentação.